# Is there a way to allow app permissions while not allowing them?

Tags: applications, security, permissions

I have an app (android) I want to use for something minor, so it's not a need, just a want. All it's supposed to do is control some lights. But it's asking for every permission you can think of (Chinese apps) and of course I am not about to let some LED controller app access my contacts, location and make phone calls etc. So is there a way to run an app in like a virtual environment so I can allow it to have those permissions while feeding it useless information? The app in question is BLE Remote.

Apologies I am TERRIBLE at asking questions...

Comment: Relatedly what happens if you deny permissions to the app?

Comment: You don't need all those permissions. Get another app.

Comment: It is possible if your device is rooted. If not search for open source equivalents on F-Droid or search in [Izzy's app lists](https://android.izzysoft.de/applists.php)

Comment: You could repackage the app and remove the unnecessary permissions: Decompile it with `apktool`, remove the permissions from `AndroidManifest.xml` rebuild it with apktool and then sign it with a custom key (Java keytool can generate those) signing can be done using `apksigner`from Android SDK.

Comment: It depends upon how the app is programmed. You can try using XPrivacyLua (requires a rooted device) or AppOps (from Sikka apps -- may be Chinese developers, don't know for sure). Both of these apps can restrict specific data leakage (contacts, IMEI, etc.). So even if you agree to allow XYZ permissions to your concerned apps  they still wouldn't get the data they requested.